# PySimpleGUI Attribute Error on Windows XP SP3 with Python 3.4.4

Tags: python, windows-xp, pysimplegui

Running a Python program which uses a PySimpleGUI interface on top of TkInter. Program runs well on Windows 10 and CentOS Linux workstations. Unfortunately have a job requirement to also run the program on a Windows XP Service Pack 3 PC in an isolated secret lab area, no internet, so any installations are brought in on a DVD.

Python 3.4.4 was the latest version I could find which supports Windows XP and it installs and runs fine with Tkinter up and running as well.

**PC Setup:**

Windows XP Service Pack 3

Python 3.4.4

PySimpleGUI 3.39.0

**Execution Error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PysharkLiveCapGUI.py", line 9, in <module>
sg.theme('Topanga')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'theme'

**Path to PySimpleGUI EGG:**

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

\>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg

\>>> print(sg)

<module 'PySimpleGUI' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\pysimplegui-3.39.0-py3.4.egg\\PySimpleGUI\\_*init*_.py'>

**PySimpleGUI Installation Results:**

```
C:\Python34\Downloads\dist\PySimpleGUI-3.39.0>python setup.py install
C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'long_description_content_type'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to PySimpleGUI.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing PySimpleGUI.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to PySimpleGUI.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'PySimpleGUI.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'PySimpleGUI.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\bdist.win32\egg
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\PySimpleGUI
copying build\lib\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\PySimpleGU
I
copying build\lib\PySimpleGUI\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win32\egg\PySimpleGUI
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py to PySimpleGUI.c
python-34.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win32\egg\PySimpleGUI\__init__.py to __init__.cpython
-34.pyc
creating build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PySimpleGUI.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PySimpleGUI.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
copying PySimpleGUI.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-I
NFO
copying PySimpleGUI.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win32\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\PySimpleGUI-3.39.0-py3.4.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win32\egg'
to it
removing 'build\bdist.win32\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing PySimpleGUI-3.39.0-py3.4.egg
Removing c:\python34\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI-3.39.0-py3.4.egg
Copying PySimpleGUI-3.39.0-py3.4.egg to c:\python34\lib\site-packages
PySimpleGUI 3.39.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pysimplegui-3.39.0-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for PySimpleGUI==3.39.0
Finished processing dependencies for PySimpleGUI==3.39.0
```

**Problem?:**

PySimpleGUI installation appeared to run error free. The EGG file looks fine when I inspect it using 7 Zip. Best guess is that Windows XP doesn't know how to read the EGG file although it's within a Python execution where theoretically Python has no problem importing EGG files. Any help with this issue greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jeff Stearns

Answer (score 0):

> Program runs well on Windows 10 and CentOS Linux workstations.

It should be wrong if you have code like `sg.theme` and you will get exception, no matter on Windows 10, CentOS Linux workstations.

> PySimpleGUI 3.39.0

If nothing wrong, function `sg.theme` released from 4.14.0 PySimpleGUI 23-Dec-2019.

> Python 3.4.4

"Upgrade your PySimpleGUI to the most update version" may not work for this version of python. try to use old method `sg.change_look_and_feel`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11936135/jason-yang  Appreciate your feedback, will try the change_look_and_feel. Odd thing is the same code and installations run with 3.39.0 on the CentOS workstation, running with a newer version of Python, 3.6.8, which should not matter for this issue. Thanks so much, will give it a go! Need to install pyshark and some other dependencies as well which likely will require GCC, GLIB, etc, will have to track down old XP versions of those as well.

Comment: PySimpleGUI 3.39.0 don't have the function `sg.theme`, it should not work on the CentOS workstation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11936135/jason-yang   Downloaded updated version of PySimpleGUI, much better, thanks for your help!!! Probably will need to use legacy PyShark for XP, Py-1.11.0 is not supported for Python 3.4. Getting things up and running on XP is a challenge, not too suprising. Thanks again!